# Airflow DAG Scheduling at last tuesday of every month

Tags: python-3.x, airflow

I want to schedule my dag to run on the last Tuesday of every month, so for OCT, my dag should run on the 25 whereas for nov the dag should run on the 29th day. Any ideas on how I could schedule this?

Answer (score 0):

Not possible with Cron schedule, at least in the current version of Airflow.

But you can do a little hack to achieve that.
Schedule dag for any day between 21-31 of the month. Then add a new "sensor" task at the beginning of that dag which will just check what day of the week is today and if it isn't Tuesday just skip execution of downstream tasks. It should run then every day till it will match your desired day of the week.

Comment: Ok, can u help to how to create that sensor. Which sensor to use, can u give me an example @rozumir

Comment: But 21-31 of the month can trigger it for two Tuesdays...
OP requested it to be run only on last Tuesday of every month.